# (Dynamical) quantifier in search and replace

Tags: regular-expression

In VIM, using search and replace like `:%s/pat/repl/g`, is it possible to have a quantifier in the replace part?
As an example, replace every line matching `pat` by exactly 100 `#` without actually typing exactly 100 `#`'s into the command?
Something like

```
s/pat/#\{100}/g
```

which, however, doesn't work for me.

More generally, is it possible to replace matches by a captured amount of characters?
For example replace

```
This 3 is a text 5 
with some 2 numbers.
```

with

```
This XXX is a text XXXXX 
with some XX numbers.
```

using something like `:%s/\(\d\)/X\{\1}/g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for "sub-replace-expression":

```
:%s/\(\d\)/\=repeat('X', submatch(1))/g
```

With `\=` the replace string is a Vim script expression. Here the function `repeat()` is called. This functions returns a String that repeats the given String count times. The String is `X` and the count is the first match group.

See `:help sub-replace-expression` and `:help repeat()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!